# Azure Pipeline "Permission denied" when building Docker Image

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a Docker Image in an Azure Pipeline. Locally everything runs like butter, on Azure I get

`/bin/sh: 1: cannot create .npmrc: Permission denied`

with the following Dockerfile:

```
# Build stage
FROM node:14-slim AS Build

# Pass build arguments. Sensitive information allowed
# This information is not available anymore in next build stage
ARG NPM_TOKEN

# Create app directory
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Install app dependencies first
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc && \
    npm ci --only=production && \
    rm -f .npmrc

[...]
```

I am a little bit confused as:

1. On local build everything works fine
2. I am switching to another user and assume to work in that directory where the User should have enough right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright found it. home/node/app is not owned by the node user...

https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/740